# BeatifulSoup: I can print out the whole table but only it saves a row of the table to *.html file

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import codecs
import json

def results(**kwargs):
    """parse and save the data"""
    url = 'http://www.sailwx.info/shiptrack/shipposition.phtml?call=wrn5495'
    web = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    for tr in web.find_all ('tr')[4:142]:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        coordinates = ("Date/time: %s, Position: %s, Speed:%s" %\         (tds[0].text,tds[1].text, tds[3].text))
        AIS = codecs.open('AIS_Page.html', 'w', 'utf-8') 
        AIS.write(coordinates)
        AIS.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results()
    print 'Saved parsed data'
```

I can see all the rows when I print but my code only saves a single row to my file.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what is your question?

Comment: I  eventually want to make a localhost web map. So I am pulling the whole table from the above url, saving it to a *.html and *.json file and mapping it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep overwriting with `w` so you only ever see the last value, you would need to use `a` to append:

```
 AIS = codecs.open('AIS_Page.html', 'a', 'utf-8')
```

Or a smarter way is to open once outside the loop:

```
def results(**kwargs):
    """parse and save the data"""
    with codecs.open('AIS_Page.html', 'w', 'utf-8')  as AIS:
        url = 'http://www.sailwx.info/shiptrack/shipposition.phtml?call=wrn5495'
        web = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
        for tr in web.find_all ('tr')[4:142]:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            coordinates = ("Date/time: %s, Position: %s, Speed:%s" %\         (tds[0].text,tds[1].text, tds[3].text))
            AIS.write(coordinates)
```

Comment: Thank you! As a python newbie- I was confused as to why it would not save to the html if it was printing out in the term. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, it is an easy mistake to make.